# Will Wizards offer a Character Builder for D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e

For those of us who are subscribed (and get the character builder online application as well as the monster creator, among other things), will they support a 5th edition builder?

If not, will they at least keep the 4th edition one in tact?